# Can I use conditional formatting to highlight a cell for dates less than 30 days away?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have a large spreadsheet where I need to keep track of coming expiration dates and I would like dates which are within 30 days from today's date OR which have already passed to be highlighted in red.

However, all of the stuff I have found online so far results in the entire column getting highlighted or not no matter what I do.

What would the formula be for it to highlight both dates which have passed already AND dates within the next 30 days?

Comment: This is for Google Sheets, I'm assuming?

Answer (score 1):

- **yellow** for **DANGER ZONE**
- **red** for **BIOHAZARD ZONE**

[image: 11]